# In which table we should put the foreign key

Tags: database-design

For example I have a table Admin and a table Role. To do one-to-one relationship between these two tables I can put the foreign key either in the Admin or the Role table. My doubt is if its icual put the foreign key either on the Amin or Role table?

Comment: Place the foreign key in the table where you do most of the filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between Admin and Role doesn't seem to be one-to-one. It's either one to many (One Role can be assigned to multiple people, then you will have FK column in Admin table), or many-to-many (then it's gonna be a link table with 2 FKs to each table).

Comment: Thanks for your help. But in the case of a one-to-one relationship, for example, book and author tables, if a book just have one author, its one to one, i can put the foreign key either in author or book, its icual?

Comment: One author can have many books.

Answer (score 1):

The most common instance of one-to-one relationships are IS-A relationships.  For example, an auto is a vehicle, and a truck (lorry) is a vehicle.  If there is a vehicle table and an auto table, every entry in the auto table will have one entry in the vehicle table.  Every entry in the vehicle table will have zero or one entry in the auto table.

This pattern can also be called class-subclass or type-subtype.

One technique that can be used in this case is called shared-primary-key.  There is a tag for this, over in Stackoverflow.  Briefly, the PK in the auto table is a copy of the PK in the vehicle table.  This means that it's also an FK that references the vehicle table.  This enforces the one-to-zero-or-one rule, and also provides some other benefits.